# Create user with trait HasApiTokens fail

Tags: laravel

I have this code in Laravel 6. I think that is correct but get error

```php
$input = $request->all();
$input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
$user = User::create($input);
$success['token'] = $user->createToken('Albarid')->accessToken; // This line get error
$success['name'] = $user->name;

$domain = new Domain;
$domain->domain = $input['domain'];
$domain->user_id = $user->id;
$domain->save();
```

User model use

```php
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
```

Error line is about `PersonalAccessTokenFactory` in line 98

```php
protected function createRequest($client, $userId, array $scopes)
{
    return (new ServerRequest)->withParsedBody([
        'grant_type' => 'personal_access',
        'client_id' => $client->id,  // Error is here
        'client_secret' => $client->secret,
        'user_id' => $userId,
        'scope' => implode(' ', $scopes),
    ]);
}
```

error with try catch

```
{"success":false,"message":"Problem when saving on database","data":["Trying to get property 'id' of non-object",64]}
```

On tinker

```
>>> $success['token'] = $user->createToken('Albarid')->accessToken;
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in /home/abkrim/Sites/albarid/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PersonalAccessTokenFactory.php on line 98
```

Any ideas?

Afetr read some post trye a way.

for me it doesn't have a logical explanation

Re-run

```sh
php artisan passport:install 
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 3
Client secret: rWVS39yXsfvdAq9cbYR9MPQpiXNOsm9CYZrgxxH6
Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 4
Client secret: iRQZQ03uUjLXH2u2BHrY73tzef94UMcMK0yjO5B1
```

Now with 4 clients on auth_clients work fine

If in this table I has only 2 first rows, not work.

Why?

I spend a lot of time for this issue.

Comment: what error you have? Can you show error stack trace?

Comment: I add information on post

Comment: I think that you are missing this part:

First php artisan passport:client --personal

and in AuthServiceProvider, inside boot function add this line

Passport::personalAccessClientId('client-id'); i

Comment: Oh... a lot of thanks a mistake. I forget a modification on 'client-id' with a fixed number 3. That is the question. I needs put 1 if first command is passport:client --personal`

Comment: Nice. I am glad that I helped you. Have a nice day.